# Как упростить b = !b

Tags: java, оптимизация

Я любитель очень красивого и оптимального программного кода, и, возможно, мой вопрос не совсем важный. Всем известно, что код:

```
int a = 0;
...
a = a - 1;
```

можно максимально упростить до кода:

```
int a = 0;
...
a--;
```

А как можно упростить следующий код:

```
boolean b = false;
...
b = !b; // <- интересует упрощение этой строки
```

?

Comment: Дело в том, что как-то не так даже слышится "Б равно отрицание Б". Вот в случае с `int` очевидно "А минус минус" лучше звучит, чем "А равно А минус 1".

Comment: Упростить не получится, можно усложнить - `b = b ? false : true` x)

Comment: Операции `++` и `--` были специально введены т.к. операция вычитания и прибавления единицы с присвоением очень частая. Для всего остального сокращений не предусмотрено, поэтому самый короткий вариант только `b = !b`.

Comment: Если вам "как-то не так слышится", попробуйте проговаривать `=` не как "равно", а как "присвоить". "Равно" - это больше про сравнение, а для сравнения в Java используется оператор `==`.

Comment: Хотелось бы напомнить, что у всей "укорачиваемости" кода есть обратная сторона. Теряятся читабильность кода, как следствие и его качество, я считаю, что лучше написать больше, зато все четко видно, что как работает.

Comment: Эту конструкцию никак не нужно оптимизировать, при компиляции в байткод и при дальнейшей jit компиляции все без вас будет максимально оптимизировано. Оптимизировать лучше на уровне алгоритмов, или когда есть реальное "узкое место".

Comment: Для явного преобразования используется двойное логическое отрицание `!!value` или вызов `Boolean(value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отписал в комментарии, почему считаю, что это не очень хороший способ написания кода, но теперь по теме вопроса.

Можно написать следующим способом.

```
b ^= true;
```

Это значит, что в `b` ты записываешь результат `b XOR true`. Строгое ИЛИ используется для смены значения переменной `boolean` в любом случаи на противоположенное.

```
true XOR true = false
false XOR true = true
```